# Why would User.IsInRole return true, but AuthorizeAttribute not?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm securing an ASP.NET MVC 2 application, and I have a user who is in the role "Foo".

This is true:

```
User.IsInRole("Foo")
```

But yet, when I attempt to lock down a controller action like the following, the user is denied:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Foo")]
public ActionResult PrivatePage()
{
    return View();
}
```

If IsInRole reports true, why would the Authorize attribute not allow the user in?

Comment: Do you have another [Authorize] attribute, perhaps on the controller type itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be caused if you are storing persistent cookies for your forms authentication cookie.  In that scenario IsInRole may check against the cookie without verifying up to date login.

Answer (score 1):

For future people with a similar problem - it could depend on how you are actually setting up your roles on the current user.

I had a similar issue where the roles were being pulled out of the cookie in an override of `OnActionExecuting` in a base controller.  Turns out this was executing *after* the `[Authorize]` attribute, so the roles weren't actually set up when the attribute was checking for them.  The call to `User.IsInRole`, being in the View, was executing after `OnActionExecuting`, so it saw the roles fine.

So `User.IsInRole` returned what I expected, but the `[Authorize]` attribute did not.

I was able to resolve this by moving the code for getting the roles into a more sensible place, that executes before the Authorize attribute - for example, in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do stuff in here
}
```

Or even better, in your own custom attribute - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5314736/206297.

Answer (score -1):

They should both return true. Have you tried using SQL Profiler to check the queries run against the DB?

Comment: There is no database involved here. This is entirely in-memory.

Comment: What are you using for membership and role providers?  The default set up is still to use sql express (I believe).  If you haven't changed anything, you should be able to look at the sql express database.  If you are using the test providers that was with one of the project templates for mvc 2, you should be able to put some breakpoints or System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine() calls in there.

Comment: IPrincipal != SQL provider. You and Simon appear to be under that impression, but IPrincipal (User in this case) really isn't coupled to membership or role providers. You can instantiate a principal object and manipulate it programatically in memory, which is what I'm doing here.

Comment: To further clarify, I can go "httpContext.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal();" and have the code in the question operate on it, with no role or membership providers coming into play.