# User is in role "admin" but [Authorize(Roles="admin")] won't authenticate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I found a great answer on SO describing [how to set up custom user roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822548/mvc-how-to-store-assign-roles-of-authenticated-users/1826413#1826413), and I've done the same in my project.  So in my Login service I have:

```
public ActionResult Login() {
  // password authentication stuff omitted here
  var roles = GetRoles(user.Type); // returns a string e.g. "admin,user"
  var authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                    1,
                    userName,
                    DateTime.Now,
                    DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(20), // expiry
                    false,
                    roles,
                    "/");
  var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, 
    FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket));
  Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
  return new XmlResult(xmlDoc); // don't worry so much about this - returns XML as ActionResult
}
```

And in Global.asax.cs, I have (copied verbatim from the other answer):

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
  if (authCookie != null) {
    var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
    var roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
    var userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name), roles);
    Context.User = userPrincipal;
  }
}
```

Then, in my `ServicesController` class, I have:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "admin")]
//[Authorize]
public ActionResult DoAdminStuff() {
  ...
}
```

I login as a user with the "admin" role, and that works.  Then I call /services/doadminstuff - and I get access denied, even though when I put a breakpoint in Global.asax.cs, I can see that my roles do include "admin".  If I comment out the first `Authorize` attribute (with roles) and just use a plain vanilla `Authorize`, then I can access the service.

I must be missing something critical here - but where to start looking?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I would recommend you use a custom authorize attribute instead of `Application_AuthenticateRequest`:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ||
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies == null ||
            filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName] == null
        )
        {
            HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
            return;
        }

        var authCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
        var authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
        string[] roles = authTicket.UserData.Split(',');

        var userIdentity = new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name);
        var userPrincipal = new GenericPrincipal(userIdentity, roles);

        filterContext.HttpContext.User = userPrincipal;
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
[CustomAuthorize(Roles = "admin")]
public ActionResult DoAdminStuff() 
{
    ...
}
```

Also a very important thing is to ensure that when you login an authentication cookie is emitted because you return an XML file. Use FireBug to inspect whether the authentication cookie is properly sent when you try to access the url `/services/doadminstuff`.

Comment: It worked!  THANK YOU!  Tell me, why did this work, but the one in Global.asax.cs didn't?

Comment: Thanks again for your help!  Maybe you could also shed some light on this related problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6586156/7850

Comment: thanks, it works. and how can i further control which page to show and with correct message.

Answer (score 0):

I would change principal assign at first:

```
Thread.CurrentPrincipal = userPrincipal;
if (HttpContext.Current != null)
{
    HttpContext.Current.User = userPrincipal;
}
```

as ASP.NET documentation stands.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` and `RoleManager<IdentityRole>` to your `ApiController` class should solve the problem.

`[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` works just fine in this class:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class EditController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public EditController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        IConfiguration configuration,
        ApplicationDbContext context
        )
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }
}
```