# how is this.HttpContext.User.Identity populated?

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies

Does anyone know how this value gets populated ?

`this.HttpContext.User.Identity`

for some reason in my code this value is populated sometimes but other times it's not. Does this information come from the session data or is it read from a cookie?

I searched around and it seems like most people are complaining about the value of `this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` not being populated, but in this situation, all `Identity`'s attributes are empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When is HttpContext.User.Identity set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594734/when-is-httpcontext-user-identity-set)

Comment: @T.S. I added an edit to clarify that this is not a duplicate question.